# index.addObjects throws a Usage error (Algolia)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algolia

I have a very small function that I'm using to add `<p>` elements from my HTML page into an Algolia index. However, when I do `index.addObjects()`, it throws an error:

```
`Uncaught Error: Usage: index.addObjects(arrayOfObjects[, callback])
at n.addObjects (algoliasearch.min.js:3)
at search (search.js:57). `
```

My code:

```
var client = algoliasearch('username', 'password');
var index = client.initIndex('ulysses');

function search() {

    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var output = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
        output = {text: paragraphs[i].innerText};

        //index.addObjects(output, function(err, content) {
        //  console.log(content);
        //}); (copy-pasted from algolia docs)

        index.addObjects(output);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `addObjects` takes an array as first parameter. Here you are giving it an javascript object.
You can fix it by doing 

`index.addObjects([output]);`

Comment: Hmm. I tried that and it didn't work -- I put square brackets around `output` and `{text: paragraphs[i].innerText}`, but I'm still getting the Usage error. Any thoughts?

Comment: It worked! I tried again today, a few days later, and it worked for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
        output = [{text: paragraphs[i].innerText }];

        index.addObjects(output);
    };
```

This is what worked in the end.